# Sorting and printing a hash of hashes in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

Using Perl, I have a HoH similar to this:

```
%HoH = (
'A' =>  {
                   'a' => 4,
                   'b' => 18,
                   'c' => 2
               },
'B'   =>  {
                   'a'  => 1,
                   'b'  => 2
               },
'C'   =>  {
                   'a'  => 1
               },
'D'   =>  {
                   'a'  => 1,
                   'b'  => 2,
                   'c'  => 5,
                   'd'  => 9
               },
    #........ on and on and on ..... 
 );
```

For each of the capital keys, I want to print the one lower-case key that has the largest value associated with it.

example output:

```
b,b,a,d...
```

Any direction at this point would be appreciated, new to the game.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward to iterate through a hash with something like `while (($key, $val) = each %hash) { ... }`. Then all you need to do is check the value of each key and remember the highest one you see.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a good place to start learning about programming. We're here to answer specific questions, not "hey, I'm just starting, can anyone help me?" Look for some online tutorials, or maybe a community for newbies just getting started.

Comment: Figured this was a specific enough question, and I wasn't able to find this info elsewhere on the webs. Thanks to those who did offer advice and tips.

Answer (score 1):

```
use List::Util qw(reduce);

for my $k1 (sort keys %HoH) {
    my $h = $HoH{$k1};
    my $k2 = reduce { $h->{$a} > $h->{$b} ?$a :$b } keys %$h;

    print "$k1, $k2\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
 for my $k (sort keys %HoH) {
    my $h = $HoH{$k};
    my $g= (sort {$h->{$b} <=> $h->{$a}} keys %$h)[0];
    print "$k: $g \n";
 }
```

(Your original output does not much sense, because the order of the keys of `%HoH` is not fixed)

Comment: That's a nice concise solution. I would probably avoid sorting if we don't know how large the problem space is -- if he needs to do this on a hash with hundreds of thousands of keys, that could impact performance considerably.

Comment: Thanks. The output order does not matter i just ordered it to try to get the point of the question across.

Comment: It would be faster to use something like `List::Util::max()`, which runs in O(N), rather than sorting which is O(NlogN).

Comment: @AKHolland : Sure, this is a quick-to-write solution, but certainly it's suboptimal to sort the full array just for getting the max element.

Answer (score 0):

Using List::Util's reduce;

```
use List::Util qw(reduce);

use strict;
use warnings;

my %HoH = ...

for my $k (sort keys %HoH) {
    my $h = $HoH{$k};

    my $maxKey = reduce {$h->{$a} > $h->{$b} ? $a : $b} keys %$h;

    print "$k -> $maxKey\n";
}
```